# How to get message Apache Kafka on client JS?

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can Apache Kafka send message from server broker to client side (JS) directly?

Or I should use socket pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Node.JS clients for Apache Kafka ([`kafka-node`](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node) and [`kafka-js`](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs)) but for the client side I would recommend a REST API or web sockets.